# batch file runs every .REG file in a directory

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have a batch file that creates a main folder and moves files & subfolders into it. I need the batch file to run every .REG file in the main folder.

I have my main folder set as a variable (it does not end in an ending slash): %folder%

I'm trying something like this, but this is only my second day writing batch scripts, so I don't know if my syntax is messed up or what.

```
for %%i in (%folder%\*.reg) do (regedit /s %%i)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Thank you so much.

-Andrea

Comment: have you tried it? did it work? if it didn't, what exactly did it do?

Comment: yes, I tried it. The files and reg files are all moved to their correct locations, but the reg files are never run and I don't see the reg entries appear the way they do when I just straight-out call them like regedit /s thisfile.REG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your folder probably contains spaces in it, so you need to quote the %%i in the regedit part.

Comment: Eureka!!!!! You are my hero Vladimir. Thank you so much. That was it. I appreciate everyone's quick assistance. Thank you. - Andrea

Comment: Glad to help :) You probably should mark the reply as an answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `for %i in (%folder%\*.reg) do (regedit /s %i)` (removed extra %) on Win2k8R2 and it behaved as expected.  What version of Windows are you using?  What error messages or bad behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Hi Ribram, Thanks. I just tried the same but it did not work for me. I am on Vista 32-bit. The batch file will be run on versions of XP, Vista, and Windows 7... nothing older.

Answer (score 0):

I modified it a bit, and it works as expected like this:

```
for %%i in ("%~dp0"*.reg) do (regedit /s "%%i")
```